# How to correctly code for a filepath in access vba

Tags: path, export

I have variations of the below code for several buttons on a form that should export data to an excel file to a specific folder.  At some point this must have been tested and worked a few months ago but now they all go to "My Documents" folder instead of the programmed file path.  What am I missing from the below vba?  I checked several times and can't find the error!

```
Private Sub cmdPPSubAssy_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryPPSubAssy"
    
    If MsgBox("Do you want to save this file?", vbYesNoCancel, "Save File as Excel") = vbYes Then
        Dim fdl As FileDialog
        Set fdl = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        With fdl
            .InitialFileName = "K:CONTROLLED_DOCS\Drawings, CasaBella (SDRxxx)\PP SubAssemblies\" & [Forms]![frmPP]![ProjectPlan] & " Sub Assembly" & ".xlsx"
        End With
        If fdl.Show Then
            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qryPPSubAssy", acFormatXLSX, fdl.SelectedItems(1), True
            DoCmd.Close acQuery, "qryPPSubAssy", acSaveNo
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

There are about 8 buttons with similar code and only one of them writes to to the correct file path but I can't see what is wrong with the other buttons' vba.  In other words the below code works while the above code does not.

```
Private Sub cmdSOFabBOMPriorityExcel_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qrySOFabBOMtest5"
    
    If MsgBox("Do you want to save this file?", vbYesNoCancel, "Save File as Excel") = vbYes Then
        Dim fd As FileDialog
        Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        With fd
            .InitialFileName = "K:\CONTROLLED_DOCS\Drawings, CasaBella (SDRxxx)\SO Fab BOMs\" & [Forms]![frmSalesOrderEntryCabs]![SalesOrder] & " Fab Components BOM" & ".xlsx"
        End With
        If fd.Show Then
            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qrySOFabBOMtest5", acFormatXLSX, fd.SelectedItems(1), True
        End If

    DoCmd.Close acQuery, "qrySOFabBOMtest5", acSaveNo
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: After testing 8 different buttons with the same variation of the above code only 1 of them works!  But I don't see any difference between this code and the others.